# How to simplify $\ln{\left(x + \ln{\left(x + \ln{\left(x + ...\right)}\right)}\right)}$.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have tried the following:

$s = \ln{\left(x + \ln{\left(x + \ln{\left(x + ...\right)}\right)}\right)}$

$s = \ln{\left(s + x\right)}$

$e^{s} = s + x$

However, I am unsure as to how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: there is no closed form for your last equation at least as long if you don't use special functions

Comment: @tired What special functions would you have to use?

Comment: There's also the issue of (1) the definition of the expression (though there's a natural choice for this) as well as (2) the issue of convergence of the sequence we presumably defined in (1).

Comment: [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: For $x$ minimally above $x$, it seems $s\approx \sqrt{2(x-1)}$ seems empirically reasonable, while for large $x$ it seems  $s\approx (1+\frac1x)\ln x$ is quite close.  Unfortunately there is a gap between them

Answer (score 1):

A solution of $e^s = x+s$ is given by
$$ s=-x-W(-e^{-x})\qquad (x\geq 1)$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Ah, I could've guessed. :') Thank you very much for such a swift response. :)